# Ionic - Cannot access external URL or make $http API calls, getting 401 Unauthorized Access Not Allowed to URL Error

Tags: http, ionic-framework, unauthorized

When I'm trying to make any $http call or external URL request in the code I get a 401 Unauthorized error as a response. I am currently running ionic run ios on my emulator and device and both show the same problem.

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) (Handshake, line 0)
http://localhost:8080/slc/Handshake?learnerId=f3f8b4f010e38602d839ece556d6dca4

I tried my IP address, but the same problem occurred. Additionally when I try to load an external file the same error occurs. I have currently allow access to localhost in my config.xml, but not sure if this plays a role in the problem.

Additionally, I also added to the $httpProvider headers to allow access, but again no progress was made.

$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

Any help would be wonderful, as I've looked through a number of forums, but I have not seen a similar issue. I am also on Ionic 1.4.3

Thank you again!

Comment: Does your problem relates to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360244/xmlhttprequest-failed-on-app/30381250#30381250 ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.xml` set `<access origin="*"/>`. Do you get the same error even when running on outside of webview?